# Core Data, how to limit on an attribute?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a Teacher entity, and student entity. Teachers can have many students. How do i fetch for all teachers but limit only 5 students per teacher?

```
entity =[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Teacher" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

returns all the teachers and all their students. How do I limit/offset an attribute? (Student)

Comment: You can't set a limit during the fetch for a referenced entity.  If you only want to display 5 students, just do it at display time

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for helping. What about memory consumption? Teachers can have millions of students, why fetch/load all this when only 5 is needed. Is there a way to not fetch a referenced entity?

Comment: Millions? I would have thought that a teacher would have, perhaps, thousands of students at most over their entire career.  Regardless, by default, Core Data will fetch the related students as faults; the entire record is not fetched until you access the object.  So, if you fetch all of the students but only access the first 5 then only the first 5 will actually be fetched.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks. So none of the students are loaded in memory until used? Because each student object can be large since it also has millions of friends and stuff. You're saying basically there's no need to limit this data since Core Data has built-in functionality to help with it?

Comment: Yes.  Those friends would also be references, and therefore fetched as faults until you actually referenced an attribute of the friend.  Millions.  You keep on using that word.  I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: @Paulw11 Appreciate the help. One last thing, can you cite the sources so I can give it to the boss and be done with it. I didn't mean millions, I meant tens and sometimes hundreds of millions. Hopefully that didn't change your answer.

Comment: If you are seriously talking about having hundreds of millions of records then you probably shouldn't be holding that data on the device; it should be on a server somewhere with the app just querying it over the network.  You can read about the relationship faulting here - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506813-relationshipkeypathsforprefetchi

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365751/how-to-review-this-suggested-edit

Answer (score 0):

To limit the results based on the count of relationship to `students`, you use a fetch predicate that includes the `@count` aggregate operator. That would look something like

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"students.@count < 5"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

That will filter the results based on the number of objects in the `students` relationship. A `Teacher` may have any number of students but this will only get those with less than 5.

Comment: Thanks for your help, what I really need is all teachers but just return 5 students per teacher. Is there really no way to do this? (aside from fetching all and manually going into each object and pick 5)

Comment: What test would you use to select those 5? What distinguishes the 5 you want from the rest of the group?

Comment: Any heuristic works, could be random 5, or latest 5; doesn't really matter. I just need 5 students per teach and not 5 million. All I want is: "All teachers and each teacher containing no more than 5 students". Thoughts?